# Excel VBA - Range.Copy transpose paste

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

I am following the help menu for `PasteSpecial` but I cannot seem to get my code to work without an error.

I want to take `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1","A5")` and paste transpose to `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1","E1")`.

What is the most simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would just like to recommend that you [use the Transpose Worksheet method rather than abusing clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13176360/429091).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not putting the pastspecial command on a new line.

Comment: I had to paste the transpose to a different set of cells. So, if copied from A1:B5, had to past to A6

Answer (score 13):

Here's an efficient option that doesn't use the clipboard.

```vb
Sub transposeAndPasteRow(rowToCopy As Range, pasteTarget As Range)
    pasteTarget.Resize(rowToCopy.Columns.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rowToCopy.Value)
End Sub
```

Use it like this.

```vb
Sub test()
    Call transposeAndPasteRow(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5"), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

Comment: This is better way to do it. Especially if you are looking for high performance. Thanks for the code!

Comment: The most underrated answer in all of stack exchange.

Comment: When I use this code the `pasteTarget` limits the amount of cells that get pasted. For example, when copying this code it will only paste the value from `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` to `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")`. However when I modify the code to `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1")` it works properly. The main issue with this arises obviously when the range of cells to copy is dynamic, and if the paste target is too small it won't copy everything, and if it is too large it will place `#N/A` in the leading cells.

Comment: @StevenPomponio The paste target only needs to be the first cell of your target range. The rowToCopy is the only place your dynamic range needs to apply.

Comment: In order for me to get it to work properly Copy Range("A1:A5") to Range("A1:E1") I needed to modify your first code to the following:
`pasteTarget.Resize(, rowToCopy.Rows.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rowToCopy.Value)`. With the main change to the `Resize` argument.

Comment: You created a different function called `transposeAndPasteColumn`. 

Answer (score 2):

**WorksheetFunction Transpose()**

Instead of copying, pasting via PasteSpecial, and using the `Transpose` option you can simply type a formula

```
    =TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:A5)
```

or if you prefer VBA:

```
    Dim v
    v = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:A5"))
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(v)) = v
```

**Note**: *alternatively you could use late-bound `Application.Transpose` instead.*

[MS help reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027) states that having a current version of **Microsoft 365**, one can simply input the formula in the top-left-cell of the target range, otherwise the formula must be entered as a legacy array formula via **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to confirm it.

**Versions**
Excel vers. 2007+, Mac since 2011, Excel for Microsoft 365