# Transpose a range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am Trying to Transpose a range of cells in Excel through VBA macro but I am getting some errors, mostly Error 91.

I am pretty new to VBA and don't have much idea about functions either.

```
Range(InRng).Select
Set Range1 = Selection
Dim DestRange As Range
Set DestRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range1)
```

After going through a couple of forums, this is what I have come up with. One thing to note is that I don't have to copy them into any other cells.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a co-variance method and in the option window the user will have the option to select the range and then choose either by columns or rows, this will then affect the resulting covariance matrix.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This gets you X and X' as variant arrays you can pass to another function.

```
Dim X() As Variant
Dim XT() As Variant
X = ActiveSheet.Range("InRng").Value2
XT = Application.Transpose(X)
```

To have the transposed values as a range, you have to pass it via a worksheet as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175468/1706564). Without seeing how your covariance function works it's hard to see what you need.

Comment: The Co-variance function that I have accepts range a parameter, what the above code is returning is a variant, a quick Google search it shows it's not possible to convert variant to Range. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Shouldn't it be Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(X)

Comment: @Andrew U See the other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24961259/1706564)

Answer (score 7):

First copy the source range then paste-special on target range with Transpose:=True, short sample:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
  Dim sourceRange As Range
  Dim targetRange As Range

  Set sourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1))
  Set targetRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 1)

  sourceRange.Copy
  targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

The Transpose function takes parameter of type Varaiant and returns Variant.

```
  Sub transposeTest()
    Dim transposedVariant As Variant
    Dim sourceRowRange As Range
    Dim sourceRowRangeVariant As Variant

    Set sourceRowRange = Range("A1:H1") ' one row, eight columns
    sourceRowRangeVariant = sourceRowRange.Value
    transposedVariant = Application.Transpose(sourceRowRangeVariant)

    Dim rangeFilledWithTransposedData As Range
    Set rangeFilledWithTransposedData = Range("I1:I8") ' eight rows, one column
    rangeFilledWithTransposedData.Value = transposedVariant
  End Sub
```

I will try to explaine the purpose of '**calling transpose twice**'. 
If u have **row data** in Excel e.g. **"a1:h1"** then the **Range("a1:h1").Value** is a **2D Variant-Array** with dimmensions **1 to 1, 1 to 8**. 
When u call **Transpose(Range("a1:h1").Value)** then u get transposed **2D Variant Array** with dimensions **1 to 8, 1 to 1**. And if u call **Transpose(Transpose(Range("a1:h1").Value))** u get **1D Variant Array** with dimension **1 to 8.**

First Transpose changes row to column and second transpose changes the column back to row but with **just one dimension**.

If the source range would have more rows (columns) e.g. **"a1:h3"** then Transpose function just changes the dimensions like this: **1 to 3, 1 to 8 Transposes to 1 to 8, 1 to 3 and vice versa.**

Hope i did not confuse u, my english is bad, sorry :-).

Comment: The issue with this approach is that I cannot copy the range into cells. I just need the raw values transposed which I can then pass onto a function that calculates Co-variance.

Comment: I tried your updated code, but the SourceRowRangeVariant and transposedVariant have the same values after running the function. This has been fixed now. You were calling Application.Transpose Twice in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do this. Here is how to create a co-variance method:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqAfC4JXd4A

Alternatively you can use statistical analysis package that Excel has.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I need to create an Macro to do it. I have the forumla and It's working fine for me. The only issue is integrating Transpose function as well

Comment: Then I'm not sure if you understand how to use ˇApplication.WorksheetFunction.ˇ correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly in reference to prefacing "transpose", by the book, either one will work; i.e., application.transpose() OR worksheetfunction.transpose(), and by experience, if you really like typing, application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose() will work also-

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you.

```
Sub CombineColumns1()
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim xNextRow As Long
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveSheet
        xTxt = .RangeSelection.Address
        Set xRng = Application.InputBox("please select the data range", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
        If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        j = xRng.Columns(1).Column
        For i = 4 To xRng.Columns.Count Step 3
            'Need to recalculate the last row, as some of the final columns may not have data in all rows
            xNextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            .Range(xRng.Cells(1, i), xRng.Cells(xRng.Rows.Count, i + 2)).Copy .Cells(xNextRow, j)
            .Range(xRng.Cells(1, i), xRng.Cells(xRng.Rows.Count, i + 2)).Clear
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

You could do this too.

```
Sub TransposeFormulas()
    Dim vFormulas As Variant
    Dim oSel As Range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a range of cells first.", _
                vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Transpose formulas"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set oSel = Selection
    vFormulas = oSel.Formula
    vFormulas = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vFormulas)
    oSel.Offset(oSel.Rows.Count + 2).Resize(oSel.Columns.Count, oSel.Rows.Count).Formula = vFormulas
End Sub
```

See this for more info.

http://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/transposing.htm

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to copy and transpose the values in the clipboard you can use the following makro:

```
Sub PasteVal()
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```