# Transpose Data from every other Row to Columns

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, transpose, vba

I have a large set of imported telecomm data in MS Excel that has existing data fields located in Rows A1:L1, and part of the data already exist in Rows A:H; and the remaining data I need to transpose are located in Column A the 2nd through 5th cell of each record with a space (blank cell) separating each unique record. (see image 1)

Data Table Field Headers

NPA-NXX | STATE |   COMPANY |   OCN | RATE CENTER | CLLI | ASSIGN DATE | PREFIX TYPE | SWITCH NAME | SWITCH TYPE | LATA | TANDEM

Cell: A2:H2

318-704 | LA | CEBRIDGE TELECOM LA, LLC D/B/A | 260H | ALEXANDRIA | ALXNLAMAXKX | 11/15/2013 | Prefix Type: CLEC

Cell: A3:A6

Switch Name: N/A
Switch Type: N/A
LATA: Shreveport LA (486)
Tandem: N/A

[TelcoDataImage1 - Rows and Columns separated by a Space and Existing Data Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWbFy.jpg)

I would like either using a MS Excel formula (preferably) or VBA code, that will transpose the 2nd to the 5th Column of each data record and transpose data in to the adjacent Row I:L. (see image 2)

[TelcoData2 - Transpose 2nd - 5th column data to adjacent rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EES7.jpg)

Data Table Field Headers

NPA-NXX | STATE |   COMPANY |   OCN | RATE CENTER | CLLI | ASSIGN DATE | PREFIX TYPE | SWITCH NAME | SWITCH TYPE | LATA | TANDEM

Cell: A2:L2 (Newly outputted transposed data)

318-704 | LA | CEBRIDGE TELECOM LA, LLC D/B/A | 260H | ALEXANDRIA | ALXNLAMAXKX | 11/15/2013 | Prefix Type: CLEC | Switch Name: N/A | Switch Type: N/A | LATA: Shreveport LA (486) | Tandem: N/A

I'm an Excel person without a great deal of VBA (Macro) experience, but will seriously consider at this point... thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a classic task for [PowerQuery](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605). On the matter of VBA, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174916/transpose-a-range-in-vba).

Comment: In the example data, you always have: "Switch name", "Switch type", "Lata", "Tandem" and blank line in that sequence.  Is this true of the full dataset?  You have put "Switch name", "Switch type" and so on in the header line. Do you really want to keep them in the data? This is a trivial problem with VBA which you should learn because, in my experience, problems like this occur regularly. If you are interested in a VBA solution I will give you a start.

Comment: Yes, the sequence of datasets (i.e.  Switch Name, Switch Type, LATA and Tandem) located as the 2nd through 5th row of each cell are always in specific manner.  I would like to get the mentioned  datasets placed and transposed adjacent right of the completed record Column H.  With respect to keeping or removing the data field names associated with each record does not matter, either way, due to the fact the data when transposed will be placed in the pre-defined Header Field Names... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you learn VBA. Throughout my career I found myself accumulating data relevant to the task at hand. The ability to manipulate that data with VBA was a lifesaver on more than one occasion.  VBA as a language is not particularly difficult to learn.  The most difficult part for me was the Excel Object Model: Excel managing multiple workbooks each with multiple worksheets each with rows, columns, ranges and cells and each of them having properties.  If you are an experienced Excel user, you may find you are already familiar with much of the Excel Object Model although you probably don’t know that name.

Search for “Excel VBA tutorial”.  There are many to choose from so pick one that matching your learning style.  I prefer books so I visited a good library, reviewed their Excel VBA Primers, and borrowed the ones I liked the best to try at home.  Finally I bought the one I preferred as a permanent reference which I still look at from time-to-time.  I found the time to learn VBA and the Excel Object Model quickly repaid itself.

You say “Yes, the sequence of datasets (i.e. Switch Name, Switch Type, LATA and Tandem) located as the 2nd through 5th row of each cell are always in specific manner.”  I am sure you believe that but I don’t.

At one time during my working life I was involved in transforming and merging workbooks.  We would get workbooks every week or month from various sources and create consolidated workbooks containing the data of interest to us in a format convenient for our data analysts to process.  Each new source workbook were supposed to be the same format as its predecessor but time and again we would find an extra column or an extra row type or an obsolete column or row type removed.  If the consolidate macro simply assumed the data was correct and merged it blindly, it might work but create a corrupt workbook.  Fortunately not on my watch, there was one case where it was some months before a minor change was noticed.  It was a massive amount of work to locate the last uncorrupted, consolidated workbook and all the source workbooks and then build a new workbook.  I am probably paranoid but I check every dataset I did not create.

My macro checks every row of your input worksheet to be one of the specified formats and will stop if a row is not as expected.  The macro cannot know how to fix the problem but at least the user is warned that a problem exists.  I recommend this approach which Microsoft calls “defensive programming”.

I think everything else I want to say is within the macro.

Create a new, macro-enabled version of your workbook, add the code below and try it. Be ready to report any problems.

Come back with questions as necessary.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveSubLinesToMain()

  ' I do not know from your question if this is a one-off tranformation or if you will need
  ' to use the macro repeatedly as new worksheets in the initial format are created by some
  ' other process. For a one-off macro, brief documentation may be acceptable. But any macro
  ' that is used repeatedly will also most certainly need updating. Trying to decipher an
  ' inadequately documented macro that you wrote six months ago or which some one else wrote
  ' is a nightmare.

  ' Do not run this macro against the master copy of the data since it transforms the data in
  ' situ. The macro is designed to carry on following an error but you must have a master copy
  ' so you can start again if the macro cannot carry on after an error.

  ' This macro updates worksheet "Data". If you worksheet has a different name, change
  ' the statement:
  '   With Worksheets("Data").

  ' Ths macro expects to find:
  '  * Row 1: Header row which is ignored
  '  * Row 2: First data row. If there are more header rows change the statement:
  '             Const ColRowDataFirst As Long = 2
  '  * The first data row must be what is named here as a main row.  That is a row starting with
  '    an NPA-NXX number.  A main row is recognised by the first character of the NPA-NXX column
  '    being numeric.
  '  * A main row may be followed by several row which are named here as a sub rows. The macro
  '    allows for there being no sub rows so the macro can be restarted on a partially processed
  '    worksheet.
  '  * The sub rows are recognised by their leading characters:
  '      "Switch Name: "
  '      "Switch Type: "
  '      "LATA: "
  '      "Tandem: "
  '  * There may also be blank lines which are ignored.
  '  * If a sub row is encountered that does not match one of those listed above, the macro will
  '    stop to allow an examination of the error situation and, when restarted, will terminate
  '    itself. You will have to decide how to update the macro to handle the error situation.
  '    Once the macro has been updated, it should be possible to restart the macro which will
  '    step over the already processed rows and continue with the unprocessed row. If this fails
  '    you will have to overwrite the partially processed worksheet with the master copy of the
  '    original data.
  '  * The block, main row and zero or more sub rows, may be repeated an indefinite number of
  '    times.
  '  * For each block, the macro copies the values from the sub rows to specified columns within
  '    their main row and then the sub rows.


  ' The statements to access a cell need a row and column number. You can use literals but with
  ' larger number of columns or special rows it can all become very confusing.  A const (constant)
  ' statement allows you to define a name to replace the literal which makes your code more
  ' readable. More importantly, what happens if a new sub row is introduced and the Lata and
  ' Tandem columns are to be moved. This is a tiny macro and finding all the 11s and 12s which are
  ' column numbers and replacing them will not be be too difficult.  This is not true of a large
  ' macro.  But updating the const statements defining ColLata and ColTandem updates every
  ' reference to these columns through the module.
  Const ColNpa As Long = 1
  Const ColName As Long = 9
  Const ColType As Long = 10
  Const ColLata As Long = 11
  Const ColTandem As Long = 12
  Const RowDataFirst As Long = 2

  Dim NpaValue As String
  Dim NumRowsToDelete As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowCrntMain As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  ' Without this statement, the screen is repainted for every change.  Since I am deleting
  ' rows this will substantially increase the run time for no advantage.
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' As stated above replace "Data" with the name of your worksheet.
  With Worksheets("Data")

    ' This is the easiest way of locating the last row with data if you know that column ColNpa
    ' will have a value on every row.
    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColNpa).End(xlUp).Row

    RowCrnt = RowDataFirst
    RowCrntMain = 0             ' No current main row

    ' I would normally use a For Loop: For RowCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowLast
    ' But I am deleting rows which will require RowCrnt and RowLast to be
    ' changed within the loop.  This is not permitted for a For Loop
    Do While RowCrnt <= RowLast
      NpaValue = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColNpa).Value
      ' This If..IfElse...IfElse statements tests for each known row type
      ' ans actions them as appropiate.  The final Else allows for an
      ' unknown row type.
      If NpaValue = "" Then
        ' Blank line
      ElseIf IsNumeric(Left$(NpaValue, 1)) Then
        ' Main row
        If RowCrntMain <> 0 Then
          ' There is a previous main row whose sub rows must be deleted
          NumRowsToDelete = RowCrnt - RowCrntMain - 1
          If NumRowsToDelete > 0 Then
            .Rows(RowCrntMain + 1 & ":" & RowCrnt - 1).Delete
            RowCrnt = RowCrnt - NumRowsToDelete
            RowLast = RowLast - NumRowsToDelete
          End If
        End If
        RowCrntMain = RowCrnt
      ElseIf Left$(NpaValue, 13) = "Switch Name: " Then
        ' Copy the value of the Switch Name row to column ColName on the main row.
        ' Do the same for all the other sub rows.
        .Cells(RowCrntMain, ColName).Value = Trim(Mid$(NpaValue, 14))
      ElseIf Left$(NpaValue, 13) = "Switch Type: " Then
        .Cells(RowCrntMain, ColType).Value = Trim(Mid$(NpaValue, 14))
      ElseIf Left$(NpaValue, 6) = "LATA: " Then
        .Cells(RowCrntMain, ColLata).Value = Trim(Mid$(NpaValue, 7))
      ElseIf Left$(NpaValue, 8) = "Tandem: " Then
        .Cells(RowCrntMain, ColTandem).Value = Trim(Mid$(NpaValue, 9))
      Else
        ' Row not recognised
        ' If code stops here try to identify why. Terminate the macro
        ' or press F5 and it will terminate itself.
        Debug.Assert False
        Exit Sub
      End If
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
    Loop

    ' Delete final block of sub-lines, if any
    If RowCrntMain <> 0 Then
      ' There is a previous main row whose sub rows must be deleted
      NumRowsToDelete = RowCrnt - RowCrntMain - 1
      If NumRowsToDelete > 0 Then
        .Rows(RowCrntMain + 1 & ":" & RowCrnt - 1).Delete
      End If
    End If

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tony, Tony and Tony, thank you so very much, it works like a charm, no further explanation needed.  Thank you so very much... Thanks

Comment: Tony, I just realized/noticed that the datasets whereas I indicated Switch Name, Switch Type, LATA and Tandem are represented in each cell this is not correct, thus, when the macro runs, if the name field is not present it returns an error message "Debug.Alert False".  I would like to know if you're able to perform the same Macro, that simply Copies the entire data associated in each field ignoring whether data field name(s) are TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: @Miaka3. I had already written the extra explanation before I saw your comment. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: @Miaka3. Your comment of an hour ago has just appeared. I do not understand your comment. I have tested the code to work even if some of the standard rows are missing. It hits `Debug.Alert False` if finds a row that is not one of those expected. When you hit `Debug.Alert False`, hover over RowCrnt. The number of the problem row will be displayed. Try to determine why that row is not as expected. Could the case be wrong?  I test for "Switch Name: ".  Lower case N or a missing colon and the row will not be recognised.

Comment: Tony, thanks for your reply.  Yes, your macro works extremely perfect... I did however notice that when a dataset field name such as "Tandem" is not present in the field name to be transposed it came up with the message "Debug.Alert False".  I was simply wondering if you were able to duplicate the macro, but instead allow the dataset field names to remain and transpose the entire cell in to the adjacent columns.  If not, I thank you for your great help.

Comment: @Miaka3. Look at the statements starting on line 87. The value in column "A" (ColNpa) has been copied to NpaValue. The If...ElseIf...ElseIf... statement tests NpaValue for each of the expected conditions and takes the appropriate action. For example, if NpaValue is "Tandem: abcdef" then "abcdef" is copied to column ColTandem (= 12 = "L"). If I understand correctly, sometimes the keyword "Tandem: " is omitted. From your earlier comment, "Switch Name" could also be omitted. What do what to happen if the keyword is omitted?

Comment: The macro could guess from the sequence. So the first sub row is "Switch Name" even if the keyword is omitted. Would this be reliable? If keywords are sometimes omitted by error, what other errors might exist? Another choice would be to ignore blocks containing an error.