# VBA: transpose last row

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I am trying to transpose the last row of my spreadsheet so that it becomes a column.

I have started such that I retrieve the last column/row number of the spreadsheet but I don't know how to make it an array to transpose it with `Application.transpose(myarray)` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myarray)`

```
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: In which column should the data be placed ??

Comment: Hello - in column A

Comment: From what I can tell, this is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174916/transpose-a-range-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

[image]

Running:

```
Sub xPose()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Cells(N, 1).EntireRow

    r.Copy
    Cells(N + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    r.Delete
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed and it works like a charm - I am grateful for people like you helping newbies out!

Comment: @pdx  We are ALL newbies in some sense.

Comment: if you ever have some time... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507901/transpose-from-rows-to-column-vba