# Transpose from rows to column (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

My question is: how to transpose the *last four rows* of the column G into different columns?

I usually use this static code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("A1:A5").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet9").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

But it doesn't allow me to stay on the same Sheet.

So I am trying to combine it with this code:

```
Dim r As Range, N As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set r = Cells(N, 1).EntireRow

r.Copy
Cells(N + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
r.Delete
```

Before
[image]

After

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing: are you working on ColA or ColG?

Comment: Sorry, it is confusing indeed. I am using ColG - ColA was a snippet of another code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Dim c As Range, v

'find last-used cell in ColG
Set c = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)

With c.offset(-3,0) 'starting with the cell 3 rows above the last-used cell...
    v = .resize(4,1).value      'get the value of the 4-row/1-col range below
    .resize(4,1).clearcontents  '...then clear that range
    .resize(1,4).value = Application.Transpose(v) 'place the values in a row
End with
```

Comment: Worked really well, thanks! Grateful if you could write down a quick explanation of your code!