# Transpose columns to rows using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In column A-D I do have attributes, E-NE I do have values for every day of the year. I would like to create a loop so I have the dates transposed to rows (which are on row 1 as titles), A-D (on row 2, below the title) doesn't get transposed but copied to B-E on every row next to the dates and the values the values corresponding to dates (on row 2 E-NE) get the transposed to the respective row.
Of course I do have multiple rows (2000) hence will translate to 600000 rows!
Let me know if you think this issue should be solved using SQL as amount of data gets to big.

Any help much appreciated!

Cheers,
FloHan

Comment: What have you tried so far? In general, try using the macro recorder and the `Transpose` option of the Excel `paste special`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose a range in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174916/transpose-a-range-in-vba)