# Excel Macro copy and transpose data to other workbook with special condition

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I am still new to macro. I have data in first workbook with 300 rows of data in one column.I need to transpose every 6 rows of data to 6 columns in other workbook.
For example data from A1:A6 must be transposed to A1:F1. Again data from A7:A14 must be transposed to A2:F2.

I have this code. The data is saved on vDB in array

```
Dim vDB
    vDB = rsData.getRows
         TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1) + 1, UBound(vDB, 2) + 1) = vDB
```

With this code, I am able to copy and transpose data to other workbook. But it only works from one column to one row. I cannot find the way to do for every 6 rows to 6 column.
Is there any way to transpose data for every 6 rows to 6 column with my code above? I appreciate for the help.

Comment: Is it okay if use `....Copy ....PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`?

Comment: No, because in my code I used library which it will copy data from closed workbook.

Comment: Try looking at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174916/transpose-a-range-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `GetRows`. After getting your RecordSet `rsData`, use this code:

```
Dim i As Long
Do Until rsData.EOF
  targetRange.Cells(1 + Int(i / 6), 1 + i Mod 6).value = rsData.Fields(0).value
  i = i + 1
  rsData.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: it not transpose the data. The data need to be transposed.

Comment: @AdryanPermana *"A1:A6 must be transposed to A1:F1. Again data from A7:A14 must be transposed to A2:F2"* the suggested code is to put the data directly from the recordset `rsData` in the way you described. It supposes that your recordset has one field (column) and instead of putting the values in one column, it puts them in `A1:F1` then `A2:F2` and so on.

Comment: sorry my mistake. I did something wrong. It works. Thanks