# Is there a way to import horizontal data into Excel columns?

Tags: excel, csv, import

If I have a file that is something like:

```
header1: 123, 122, 345, 66777
header2: 566, 766, 213, 3453

...
```

Is there a way to import it into Excel such that each row in the file becomes a column in Excel, or do I need to make some script to flip it first and just import it as a csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Power Query in Excel. Import the data into the Power Query editor, transpose it, then use first row as header.

Comment: There is something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174916/transpose-a-range-in-vba. You can refer to it and try to modify from it.