# VBA copy column from sheet 1 and transpose paste into row in sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro to copy data from column C (to the last full row) and transpose paste that data into row 1 on sheet 2. I cannot get my code to work. I am getting a Run-time error 1004 for the Paste line of code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ColumnRow()

    Dim lRow As Long

        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1" & lRow).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174916/transpose-a-range-in-vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things.

(1) Specify the sheet for `lRow`

(2) Syntax for range `Range("C1" & lRow)` was off - see below

```
Sub ColumnRow()

Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'add sheet ref
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lRow).Copy 'specify full range
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Got it thanks, just need to put the 1 in Cells(Rows.Count, 1) as a 3 for column C

Comment: One thing I omitted to mention is that this code will overwite as it always pastes to A1.