# how to copy and paste data from horizontal to vertical

Tags: excel, vba

The data in my original spreadsheet is listed horizontally. For instance:

```
A B C D E

F G H G I

J K L M N

O P Q R S
```

I would like to arrange this table in a vertical way. like this below:

```
A

B

C

D

E

F

G
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please know this is not a code writing service, so please read the following: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Provide code that you have tried and if/when you run into issues/errors post them too.

Comment: Look at the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13176360/4717755) to help get you started.

Comment: Is your table jagged, or do all rows have the same number of columns with values?

Comment: Hi, All rows have the same no. of columns with values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable with INDEX and some math:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$4,ROUNDUP(ROW(1:1)/COLUMNS($A$1:$E4),0),MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,COLUMNS($A$1:$E4))+1)
```

Explanation:

- `ROUNDUP(ROW(1:1)/COLUMNS($A$1:$E4),0)`: creates the repeating sequence: 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2... when dragged down.
- `MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,COLUMNS($A$1:$E4))+1`: creates the repeating sequence: 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5... when dragged down.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/897212/fill-cells-with-a-repetitive-pattern-in-excel) also explains the creation of those repeating sequences.

[image]

Comment: Great function! It would be useful to include a breakdown of the formula in the answer to make it more obvious how this is working though. As an aside you could replace the instances of 5 with COLUMNS($A$1:$E$4) which could also lead to easier implementation of dynamic resizing of a named range for more advanced calculations as well.

Comment: @Tragamor yeah I thought about using COLUMNS, that's a good idea.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you very much, I am new to the community and i will make sure to follow the proper asking rules from next time. As for this one, you saved me. Thanks a lot.