# How to vb.net copy array to excel spreadsheet

Tags: vb.net

I have created an array in VB and want to copy the whole array to an excel spreadsheet rather than doing it a line at a time. This will make the process much quicker.

The array code at VB end is like as follows

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("A2").Resize(x, y).Value = MyArray
```

The excel spreadsheet has headings

```
Name, Dept, Salary
```

Rather than being displayed as

```
Name     Dept        Salary
Smith    Accounts    10000
Green    Sales       14500 
Brown    Accounts    12000
```

It is getting displayed as

```
Name       Dept   Salary
Smith      Green  Brown
Accounts   Sales  Accounts
10000      14500  12000
```

Comment: *This will make the process much quicker* - really? How do you know? Where is the slow inefficient code right now (it's not in your question)? Looks like the simplest thing would be to create your array the other way round? Where's the code that creates the array (it's not in your question either) ?

Comment: Please read up on how to post monospace preformatted text on SO; you keep rolling back other people's edits to make your post readable, reverting their sensible edits into this unreadable mess

Comment: You need to fix the array or transpose the data in excel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174916/transpose-a-range-in-vba

Comment: Thanks mike, transpose worked for me