# transpose data from 2 sheets

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

there are, in a sense, two answers to this question here at overflow. So, I'd like to ask which is "better"

First solution can be found here
[Excel VBA - Range.Copy transpose paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852717/excel-vba-range-copy-transpose-paste)
and essentially it suggests this

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

I haven't yet tied this, but it looks as if it should work

Next solution can be found here
[Transpose a range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174916/transpose-a-range-in-vba)
and uses this method

```
Sub transposeTest()
Dim transposedVariant As Variant
Dim sourceRowRange As Range
Dim sourceRowRangeVariant As Variant

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select  ' NOTE: I added this

    Set sourceRowRange = Range("A1:H1") ' one row, eight columns
    sourceRowRangeVariant = sourceRowRange.Value
    transposedVariant = Application.Transpose(sourceRowRangeVariant)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select  ' NOTE: I added this

    Dim rangeFilledWithTransposedData As Range
    Set rangeFilledWithTransposedData = Range("I1:I8") ' eight rows, one column
    rangeFilledWithTransposedData.Value = transposedVariant
End Sub
```

I have employed this and yes it does work, although I had to use Sheets("Sheet1").Select and Sheets("Sheet2").Select in the blank space above.  I tried all in one statement like
Set sourceRowRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(1, 8)), but apparently the sheet must be selected before a range can be Set to it.

I'm hoping some one could explain why one is better than the other.

Comment: have you thought about trying them both and see which one fits better with your current situation, keeping in mind understanding of what the code is doing and if it's something you can modify given your current ability?  If you work through that, you should have an idea which is "better" than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but too big for a comment...

`Cells()` without a worksheet qualifier always defaults to the current Active sheet, so you should do something like this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sourceRowRange = .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(1, 8))
End With
```

Or (simpler):

```
Set sourceRowRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Resize(1,8)
```

Comment: Tim, I would like to thank you for your reply.  I don't know which pile of sand I've had my head buried in, but I've never heard of Resize.  I wrote a bit of code to generate a table so that I could easily vary the size.  I then wrote some code to try out your suggestion and was thrilled.  Pretty cool.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

On such a small set of data, you can't say which is better. In your scenario, my personal choice would be **Option1**. Why? Because it is less code. :)

**Pros of Option 1**

1. Less code. Just two lines.
2. It is faster.

**Cons of Option 1**

Uses the clipboard so that may create problems if not used judiciously.

For example

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("X1").Value= "Sid"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

The problem with this is Excel clears the clipboard if you perform any action (Such as writing to a cell) and hence the next `PasteSpecial` line will fail as it doesn't find anything in the clipboard. There have been instances when even the below two lines will fail on large set of data.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Reason being, the data has not been fully placed in the clipboard and the next line is executed and it fails as it doesn't find anything in the clipboard. So to counter it, one can use the below method

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
DoEvents
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

**Pros of Option 2**

Doesn't use the clipboard. The data is stored in the array. Once the data is stored, it can be used many times. You don't have to "Copy" the data again and again as you may have to do in case of **Option1** if the clipboard gets cleared.

**Cons of Option 2**

As compared to **Option1**, it has more lines of code.

Comment: Siddharth, Thank you for your reply.  Very clear.  Answers my question perfectly