# Copy row´s content to another rows but transpose in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy row values to other rows but I need them transposed. I've the following code but it doesn't work.

```
Sub Prueba()
    Worksheets("Punto 5").Range("J9:M9").Copy
    Worksheets("Punto 5").Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column)).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

I checked this answer but it didn't help me at all.
[Excel VBA - Range.Copy transpose paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852717/excel-vba-range-copy-transpose-paste/40405561#40405561)

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

just remove the Range( from the second function call

It should be:

```
Sub Prueba()
    Worksheets("Punto 5").Range("J9:M9").Copy
    ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: While that is a correct answer, I believe the OP never intended `Worksheets("Punto 5")` to *not* be active when that executes, and the chances are they wanted `ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial`.

Comment: indeed this is much better!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not by any PC to test it, but here's an alternative without Copy/Paste;

```
Sub Prueba()
    With Worksheets("Punto 5").Range("J9:M9")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
    End With
End Sub
```