# vba code. pastes values in range instead of whole column

Tags: excel, range, copy-paste, vba

Can someone help me with below issue please :)

Issue: I have below code that finds textA in Budget sheet in column A copies that row... finds sheet with same textA and pastes in d4:d15. however it is pasting through out column D instead of just in that range.

Help with : get vba to copy only B:M row range from budget sheet and paste in column d4:d15 only.

```
Sheets("Budget").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
On Error Resume Next
Selection.Find(What:="phh budget", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
If Err.Number = 91 Then
MsgBox "ERROR: 'PHH budget' could not be found."
End
End If


intRow = ActiveCell.Row
Rows(intRow & ":" & intRow).Copy
Sheets("PHH").Select
range("D3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True

range("B1").Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
range("D3:D15").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `Rows(intRow & ":" & intRow).Copy` to `Range("B" & intRow & ":M" & intRow).Copy`

Because with your first code, you are Copying the entire Row and then pasting. With the second code, You just copy from column B to M.

And i don't know if it is what you intended, but you are multiplying the values that are pasted.

## Tips:

1. You should avoid [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). So you declare the worksheet and range.
2. Try to copy [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852772/7690982) with Range.Copy and Pasting with Transpose.
3. Try using the example of the [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)
4. If you try to get rid of Select, you should also substitute: [.Select/.Activate/Selection/Activecell/Activesheet/Activeworkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718179/7690982)

Comment: thank you danieltakeshi for your help for the second time today :D It worked. I will read your tips so I can be better in future. Also yes I am multiplying with value in B1. getting to show $ in millions.