# Copy a range of cells from one worksheet to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to using VBA and need to copy data from a range of cells on one worksheet to another worksheet. I need to copy a column of cells and paste it into a row of cells e.g. A1:A4 to A1:D1. This is the code i'm using but it doesn't work the way i need it too.

```
Sub Draft()

Worksheets("Material Check").Range("B3:B6").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A2:D2")

End Sub
```

Also I need the data thats being copied over to be added to the bottom of the table on the archive sheets and i'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Use `PasteSpecial` with `Transpose:=True`.

Comment: Do you like to al the time be pasted in "A2", or in the next empty row?

Comment: @BigBen I edited my code to this but it throws up an error message               
Sub Draft()

Worksheets("Material Check").Range("B3:B6").Copy _
Worksheets("Archive").Range("A2:D2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA - Range.Copy transpose paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852717/excel-vba-range-copy-transpose-paste)

Comment: Remove the `_` - this should be two separate lines and that's the line continuation.

Comment: `Range("A2:D2")` -> `Range("A2")`.

Comment: @BigBen ah perfect that worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: @FaneDuru The next empty row

Comment: `Range("A2")` -> `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`.

Comment: @BigBen This gives an error message                                                                 
 Sub Draft()

Worksheets("Material Check").Range("B3:B6").Copy
Worksheets("Archive").Range("A2:D2" & Rows.Count)End(x1Up).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub

Comment: Make sure you copy *exactly* what I have. You've got a couple issues there.

Comment: Sub Draft()

Worksheets("Material Check").Range("B3:B6").Copy
Worksheets("Archive").Range("A2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset (1)
End Sub                                                                                                             
This throws another error

Comment: You still didn't copy exactly what I have - I don't have `A2`, but `A`. There's a big difference :-)

Comment: I tried with just A and A2. Thats why I sent the code with A2 because that was the last one I tried. But both don't work. The code I had before trying to insert after the last row worked great. Just need to get it to insert after the final row.

Comment: `Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`. Please copy (don't retype) this line :-)

Comment: That worked great now, thank you much appreciated! Is it possible to clear the formatting after its done that? As its making one of the cells on the archive page red which I don't want.

Comment: `Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible but are you able to copy separate ranges off cells of the same worksheet and onto a separate one. So for example copy cells B3:B6 and F4:F7 from the Material check sheet onto the archive sheet and on the same row?

Answer (score 0):

**Without Excel Tables**

This is a bit of an odd way to do it but if you have a lot of cells to do, it's possibly faster than copy/paste special:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive").Range("A2:D2").Formula = "=INDEX('Material Check'!$B$3:$B$6,Column())"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive").Range("A2:D2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive").Range("A2:D2").Value
```

The first line populates the destination range with a formula that pulls the data from the source, using INDEX/COLUMN to transpose the result.

The second line simply converts the formula to hard values.

**EDIT - Solution to copy the values to the bottom of the list**
**Using Excel Table**

To do this you will need to go to "Insert" --> "Table".

```
''Get a reference to your destination table
Dim Tbl1 As ListObject
Set Tbl1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Archive").ListObjects("Table1") ''Change these to your destination sheet/table names

''add a new row to the table
Dim Newrow As ListRow
Set Newrow = Tbl1.ListRows.Add

''populate the new row
With Newrow
    .Range(Tbl1.ListColumns("Column1").Index) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Material Check").Range("B3") ''change these to your destination column name and your source sheet/ranges
    .Range(Tbl1.ListColumns("Column2").Index) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Material Check").Range("B4")
    .Range(Tbl1.ListColumns("Column3").Index) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Material Check").Range("B5")
    .Range(Tbl1.ListColumns("Column4").Index) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Material Check").Range("B6")
End With
```

Comment: This doesn't bring over the formatting though, which OP might need (or might not, can't tell from the question).

Comment: No, but I took "copy data from a range of cells" to mean data only.

Comment: I don't need the formatting to carry over. But I tried the code and it didnt throw any error messages up and ran but it didn't actually paste any of the data. Also, this is my first time doing VBA which would explain by very minimal understanding and poorly worded questions haha

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code exactly? I just tried it and it works fine for me... Are all the sheet names and ranges correct? I just noticed that you also want the data adding to the bottom of the list. For this, I'd suggest using an actual table.